# How do I write a php function to show class in navigation menu url using php self

Tags: php, css, navigationbar

I'm trying to figure out how to add a css class to a `<li>` tag in my menu navigation. I'm using a template that gets included on every page of site. In the template is the menu navigation code. I need to set the css class on the `<li>` for the corresponding active page using PHP_SELF I presume?

Navigation looks like this

[image: Navigation Menu]

And this is what it should look like when the page is displayed that corresponds to the page that was clicked in the navigation menu.

[image: Navigation Menu with class="current"]

Here is the navigation menu code

```
<!-- MENU BEGIN -->
<div id="menu">
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li <?php echo $class_current; ?>><a href="technician-jobs/">Technician</a></li>
<li <?php echo $class_current; ?>><a href="programming-jobs/">Programming</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- MENU END -->
```

Here is the PHP function I am trying to create

```
function classCurrent(){
if(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == true) {
 echo ' class="current"';
}
else {
 echo '';
 }

 $current = classCurrent();
 return $current;
}
```

I know this is possible, I just can't figure it all out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is really simple actually to do this. All that needs to be done is have a variable set on the active page above the `<html>` tag preferably.

Example:

```
<?php $currentPage = 'technician';
<html>
```

So now we have this variable set on the technician page above the html tag. Now to call it in the template page on the navigation menu `<li>` all that needs to be done is the following.

```
<?php if ($currentPage=="technician") echo " class=\"current\""; ?>
```

Now just need to repeat this step for each page of the website.

This was also answered here [PHP navigation menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125318/php-navigation-menu?rq=1)

and a real good tutorial on how to do it is here http://alistapart.com/article/keepingcurrent

As a result the navigation code will end up looking something like this

```
<!-- MENU BEGIN -->
<div id="menu">
<ul id="nav">
<li<?php if ($currentPage=="home") echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li<?php if ($currentPage=="technician") echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="technician-jobs/">Technician</a></li>
<li<?php if ($currentPage=="programming") echo " class=\"current\""; ?>><a href="programming-jobs/">Programming</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- MENU END -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try specifying some base class that has variables for the corresponding menus. So like  if you are requesting the technician page:

```
Class Activmenu {
public $technician = true;}
```

alternatively you may use superglobal variables but this is safer. And in the menu you can check for the true item

if(Activemenu->technician)? echo'class="activeclass"' : 0;

Checking urls you will run into problems, if later on you have to modify your url structure.

Comment: I tried the code you gave but it breaks the page. the log error is PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in

Comment: Sorry it is just some dummy code. I suggest making a singleton pattern class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5 and setting getting its properties. If you are not already familiar with this take a look into singleton pattern and getters setters, you shall have the answer.

Comment: if I take this route, can you tell me of security flaws?

Comment: Well I'm not a security specialist, but as far as I'm concerned this is not really a security issue. You have a runtime variable in a php code that is assigned a value. None of this is visible in html. If someone can maniulate your php, your code suffers somewhere else.

Comment: thanks. I think what I need is the suggestion by Mark B on this answered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125318/php-navigation-menu?rq=1 and then a full tutorial here http://alistapart.com/article/keepingcurrent. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, Marc B and I are suggesting the same. The point is checking for variables, not urls, as your urls are likely to change in the future.